# Angular2 - Looping out result from PHP/Json

Tags: php, json, angular

Okey, so I am a Angular n00b. I have went through some guides on how to solve this problem, but I feel like I need some guidance from you after all.

**I have managed to create this:**

A (click)="checkForList()" on a button sends a http.get-request to my PHP-backend which generates json_encoded data which I have managed to console.log with Angular and that works just fine. Which means; I can receive the data into my Angular app.

**My service looks like this:**

```
getProjects() {
    return this.http.get("http://localhost/php-backend.php")
        .map(
            (response: Response) => {
                const data = response.json();
                return data;
            }
        )
        .catch(
            (error: Response) => {
                return Observable.throw("Something went wrong");
            }
        );
}
```

**And I have this constructor in my component**

```
constructor(private GetProjectList: GetProjectList) {}
    checkForList() {
        this.GetProjectList.getProjects()
            .subscribe(
                (projects: any[]) => console.log(projects),
                (error) => console.log(error)
    );
}
```

Instead of just console.logging the data. I wanna render the data in a *ngFor-loop on the DOM.

Something like this... yeah, you get it :)

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let projects for projectslist">{{ Name }}</li>
</ul>
```

I would be glad if you could help me converting my above stuff into something I can render on the DOM :)

Comment: Declare "projectlist" as an Object first then constructor(private GetProjectList: GetProjectList) {}

    checkForList() {
        this.GetProjectList.getProjects()
            .subscribe(
                (projects: any[]) => this.projectlist = projects,
                (error) => console.log(error)
    );

  }

Answer (score 1):

First the `projectList` must be defined on `this`.

```
class myComponent {
    public projectList;

    constructor(private GetProjectList: GetProjectList) {}

    checkForList() {
        this.GetProjectList.getProjects()
            .subscribe(
                (projects: any[]) => this.projectList = projects,
                (error) => console.log(error)
            );
    }
}
```

After that you can render it:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let project of projectList">{{ project.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your solution seems really simple and nice. Somehow I receive the error message "Property 'projectlist' does not exist on type 'ProjectList'.

Noob error I guess. I am missing something in your answer :)

Comment: you need to declare it before you assign a value for it:) I've edited my answer, check it:)